# Unregister a test case in Google Test

Tags: c++, googletest

The Google Test framework automatically registers tests.

We are loading a dll with tests in it (which registers the tests), unloading the dll, and then calling "RunAllTests".

The static test class objects instantiated by the TEST() macro do not unregister themselves when their destructor is called (as the dll unloads).

The end result is that the tests in the unloaded dll are still registered, so RunAllTests attempts to access invalid memory.

Is there a way around this?